# APC Cache Variable still in memory?

Tags: php, variables, caching, apc

I would like to get your insight into an PHP APC memory thing.

I am storing a variable in memory by using `apc_store('foo', $bar, 20);` which is working fine. The TTL description says:

> Time To Live; store var in the cache for ttl seconds. After the ttl
>   has passed, the stored variable will be expunged from the cache (on
>   the next request)

But if I am using `var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));` and `var_dump(apc_cache_info());` .. I can see my foo dying after 20 secs (which is correct) but the cache_info (array in cache_list) still tells me it is there. Using the deletion command actually clears it properly, but how to make sure with TTL?

Comment: Sometimes its easier to check if a value is valid and refuse to retrieve it if it's expired, rather than delete the value once it becomes invalid.

Comment: Which leaves me exactly with my question - do I need to manually delete it or will it vanish from cache? I understood it will vanish from cache as soon as TTL is done.

Comment: The documentation sort of implies that it will vanish from the cache the next time you try and retrieve it after it has expired. It does say it will be expunged from the cache **on the next request**.